# exFat Hard Drive not showing up on mac OS X 10.7.5

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb

I formatted a 1TB Seagate USB 3.0 hard drive as ExFat to be used on both a MacBook and a Windows PC. The formatting was done on Windows and there isn't any issue when I access it through Windows. I have tried the hard drive on 2 MacBooks so far and it doesn't come up on either one of them when I plug it in. The MacBooks are running OS X 10.7.5.

I was under the impression that OS X was capable of operating with exFat. You'll have to excuse my ignorance to this as I mainly work with Windows or Linux.

Any help would be appreciated and if there is a work around to this problem it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem and my IT ppl have informed me that the only solution is to reformat the drive on a Mac. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this myself as I haven't had this similar problem, but I read that it is the cluster size that you select during formatting which is the issue. If you plan to use with Mac, format the drive using a cluster size not more than 1024. 
The problems I have are kind of different with exFat and mostly when the drive is not ejected properly under mac, everytime this happens i have to do a verify/recover step which takes quite a lot of time as mine is also a 1TB drive.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this myself with no issues whatsoever, however my only difference is I formatted the drives using Mac, now this might be speculation and I don't Know how much time you have but if you're able to reformat the drive using Mac